# Excel Match not matching

Tags: excel, match, excel-match

To ensure the correct line items are included in the reconciliation, I created a `MATCH` function (as there is no other unique identifier in both files/tabs).

As there are rounding variances of +/- 0.01, I also created columns if it is unable to match to add 0.01 and to subtract 0.01.

In this example, I have a few items that do not appear as a match but when I use conditional formatting, they are showing up as a match.

I've tried using the following:

1. Text to columns function,
2. Copy paste values,
3. Copy paste to notepad and copy paste values from notepad,
4. Copy and pasting the number from tab 2 to tab 1 and then using the format painter.

The only thing that appears to be working is if I hard type these to the correct amount.

Is there another solution I may try?

Comment: Can you share an example of the data and what the output should look like?

Comment: Skip the 'helper' column(s); they may not be helping at all. Sort the data in either an ascending or descending manner and use 1 or -1 for the MATCH function's **[match_type]** parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a file.  When using the 1 or -1 it shows a match when no match actually exists.